# dispatch block does not run completely and in the mean while executes other codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have run into a big problem.
Here is my code

```
#import "NewsAppMenuVC.h"
#import "MenuController.h"
#import "NewsAppTebleCell.h"
#import "NewsAppNewsVC.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface NewsAppMenuVC ()
{
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    News *news;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *abstract;
    NSString *url;
    NSString *byLine;
    NSString *publishedDate;
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) MenuController *menuController;
@end


@implementation NewsAppMenuVC

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
self.menuController = [[MenuController alloc]init];
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


self.tableView.delegate = self;
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.menuController newsCount];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NewsAppTebleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
news = [self.menuController newsAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.newsNameLabel.text = news.newsName;
// Configure the cell...

return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//[HUD showAnimated:YES];
//NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
news = [[News alloc]init];
news  = [self.menuController newsAtIndex:indexPath.row];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self getRequiredData:news.newsName];
});



UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NewsAppNewsVC *destVC = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsAppNewsVC"];
if([dataArray count] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Array is empty");
}
else{

    destVC.dataArray = dataArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
}

}

-(void) getRequiredData:(NSString*)name
{
[HUD showAnimated:YES];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/html", @"text/xml", @"text/json" , nil];
NSLog(@"In getRequiredData method");

[manager GET:@"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/U.S./.json?limit=5&api-key=e024ff0a3fba0e538ed8625bd74cf241%3A7%3A75053716" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Within the API manager");
     jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
     jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
     //NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:jsonDictionary];
 }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Failed %@", error);
 }];

NSLog(@"Filtering results");
NSArray *resultsArray = jsonDictionary[@"results"];
//NSLog(@"Array = %@", resultsArray);
for(int i = 0; i < [resultsArray count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    title = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    abstract = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"abstract"];
    url = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"url"];
    byLine = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"byline"];
    publishedDate = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"published_date"];
    NSString *imageUrl = @"No Image";
    if([[resultDictionary objectForKey:@"multimedia"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *multimediaArray = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"multimedia"];
        if([multimediaArray count] < 3)
        {
            NSDictionary *multimedia3 = [multimediaArray objectAtIndex:0];
            imageUrl = [multimedia3 objectForKey:@"url"];
        }else
        {
            NSDictionary *multimedia3 = [multimediaArray objectAtIndex:3];
            imageUrl = [multimedia3 objectForKey:@"url"];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No multimedia");
    }


    News *newsObject = [[News alloc]initWithNewsName:news.newsName title:title abstract:abstract url:url byLine:byLine publishedDate:publishedDate imageUrl:imageUrl];


    NSLog(@"Title = %@", newsObject.title);
    NSLog(@"Abstract = %@", newsObject.abstract);
    NSLog(@"url = %@", newsObject.url);
    NSLog(@"byLine = %@", newsObject.byLine);
    NSLog(@"pub_date = %@", newsObject.publishedDate);
    NSLog(@"Image url = %@", newsObject.imageUrl);

    NSLog(@"Created an Object");


    [dataArray addObject:newsObject];
    NSLog(@"Object added successfully");
}

}
```

I am fetching data from a news API. What is needed is that the dispatch block should fetch data from the API and only then the rest of the code should work.
But in my case while the dispatch block is been run, it also executes other code outside the block which makes my result clumsy.
I would be glad if anybody can help me out.....

Comment: What this code does is that whenever the user clicks on a particular row in the table the dispatch block runs and fetches data from the API.

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest of the code"? The code after "filtering results"?  If so then you need this code to be in the completion handler block or in a function called from the completion block

Comment: By rest of the code i mean the code after the dispatch block @Paulw11

Comment: The problem am facing is that my code takes time to fetch data from the API(around 5-6secs). In that time the code outside the dispatch block executes which results in an empty dataArray. I use that dataArray to count the number of rows for the table.

Comment: I need the code outside of the dispatch block to execute only after all the data from the API has been fetched.

Comment: Then, as I said, you need to call that code from inside the dispatch block. That is the whole point of dial thing an asynchronous operation; it allows the app to keep running while the network operation completes in the background. If you have code that relies upon the result of the network operation then you need to invoke that code when the operation completes; in the dispatch block

Comment: Your tip has done half of the trick.

Comment: Another problem am facing is that everytime the same news gets loaded.I need to show the World news when the user selects the World but still it shows the previous news

Comment: I need to click 3 to 4times on a menu option to make it run and display the result on the next view controller. Do u know why does this happen ?

Comment: @RaviMehta: You are using an asynchronous API. It is _supposed_ to run in the background, while other things are happening. You'll have to live with that. Embrace it. (Because if you don't, forget about iOS programming). When your callback is called, _that's_ when you do all the work.

Comment: Is there a solution for this @gnasher729. Wait till the API fetches data and then move ahead

Answer (score 0):

put your below code in `completion handler of GET method call` instead of out side,

```
NSLog(@"Filtering results");
NSArray *resultsArray = jsonDictionary[@"results"];
//NSLog(@"Array = %@", resultsArray);
for(int i = 0; i < [resultsArray count]; i++)
{
NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:i];
title = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
abstract = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"abstract"];
url = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"url"];
byLine = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"byline"];
publishedDate = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"published_date"];
NSString *imageUrl = @"No Image";
if([[resultDictionary objectForKey:@"multimedia"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSArray *multimediaArray = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"multimedia"];
    if([multimediaArray count] < 3)
    {
        NSDictionary *multimedia3 = [multimediaArray objectAtIndex:0];
        imageUrl = [multimedia3 objectForKey:@"url"];
    }else
    {
        NSDictionary *multimedia3 = [multimediaArray objectAtIndex:3];
        imageUrl = [multimedia3 objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"No multimedia");
}


News *newsObject = [[News alloc]initWithNewsName:news.newsName title:title abstract:abstract url:url byLine:byLine publishedDate:publishedDate imageUrl:imageUrl];


NSLog(@"Title = %@", newsObject.title);
NSLog(@"Abstract = %@", newsObject.abstract);
NSLog(@"url = %@", newsObject.url);
NSLog(@"byLine = %@", newsObject.byLine);
NSLog(@"pub_date = %@", newsObject.publishedDate);
NSLog(@"Image url = %@", newsObject.imageUrl);

NSLog(@"Created an Object");


[dataArray addObject:newsObject];
NSLog(@"Object added successfully");
}
```

this code should be in completion handler you have write it outside.

**Update :**

```
 UIStoryboard *myStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 NewsAppNewsVC *destVC = [myStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsAppNewsVC"];
if([dataArray count] == 0)
{
NSLog(@"Array is empty");
}
else{

destVC.dataArray = dataArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
}
```

this code should also in completion handler.
try it.
put above and this all code in completion handler

hope this will help :)

Comment: Nope. Completion handler didnt work well. Still the code execution get mixed up

Comment: check my update in answer. perform navigation operations after completing getting data task

Comment: Hey guys, i found the answer. To wait till the results are fetched from the API, we need to add the code which we need to execute after data fetch from server in the success block. This waits till the API fetches data and then starts dealing with the fetched data. I am attaching the code

Comment: '[manager GET:@"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/Education/.json?limit=1&api-key=e024ff0a" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             
             jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
             jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
             //NSLog(@"Json = %@", jsonDictionary);
             [self formatFiled];
             
         }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Failed %@", error);
         }];
'

Comment: The formatFiled method contains code that should execute after data fetching from the server